# Windowssizes in WPF changes from designmode and runtime

Tags: c#, wpf

When designing applications in Visual Express C# WPF my windowsizes changes. In "design" mode everything is set up as desired but at runtime the windows are loosing some width and height ?

I have included a line of the code below that I use to setup the mainwindow.

```
<Window x:Class="CSVConvert.MainWindow" 
        xmlns="schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"; 
        xmlns:x="schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"; 
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="460" ResizeMode="NoResize">
```

Debug:
[image]

Runtime:
[image]

Just another screendump that might explains the offset. A new project with equal sizes in the mainwindow and the grid

New Project:
[image]

Any ideas to solve this problem ?

thanks

Comment: Why do you need to impose a specific window size on your users?

Comment: Show the full opening tag for the window, and any related C# property settings.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper - It's about keeping the ratios between the controls and the windows.

Comment: @HenkHolterman 'Window x:Class="CSVConvert.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="460" ResizeMode="NoResize">'

Comment: Add it to the question. And that's pretty short, are youre it shows everything?

Comment: _keeping the ratios between the controls and the windows_ - WPF has so many excelent features to do that dynamically.

Comment: I´m quite new to Stackoverflow. Should I "edit" or "Answer" my post ? I have taken some screenshots to show you the differences in outcome. [link]https://www.dropbox.com/sh/hrb5arhil9dt6a8/AAAMKsmbESpNHNhHcrxYQmtMa

Comment: The runtime version definitely looks smaller. But does it matter? I mean it looks very slick and symmetric and even better than the debug version <- Coming from an OCD freak

Comment: @TzahMama - That's because I have been compensating for width and height in Debug.

Comment: Try setting a fixed value for the row heights of your Grid, instead of using * or auto. Then, for your Window, set the width/height to auto.

Comment: @d.moncada: I've tried creating a new project with only one button in the lower, right corner. Same problem as before. I then tried to embed your suggestions and not being able to set a default size on the window dosn't seem to be my solution as the mainwindow expands to double or tripple size ?

Comment: Replace the Width/Height in the Window with `SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"` and keep the Width/Height on the Grid as in the last screenshot.

Comment: Thanks for all your help and time. The last suggestion from @HenkHolterman worked out and was the solution to my problem.